# How do I crop an ImageSurface in Cairo?

Tags: c#, gtk, cairo

I'm using the Cairo bindings for C#, and I wanted to be able to crop an ImageSurface and put it into a new ImageSurface variable, which I will then use in a seperate subroutine. The question is how would I do this properly.

Here's my code as it stands:

```
ImageSurface OutputImage = new ImageSurface (Format.Rgb24, (int)RectangleToCropTo.Width, (int)RectangleToCropTo.Height);
using (Cairo.Context cr = new Cairo.Context(OutputImage)) {
    cr.SetSource (originalImage);
    cr.Rectangle (RectangleToCropTo);
    cr.Clip ();
    cr.Paint ();
}
```

As it stands, it does actually crop the image down, and it appears to start at the correct point - but the OutputImage is offset in the x and y axis by the amount of pixels from 0,0 that the top left of the selection is. The area that the image doesn't populate is transparent.

I also tried the following:

```
ImageSurface OutputImage = new ImageSurface (Format.Rgb24, (int)RectangleToCropTo.Width, (int)RectangleToCropTo.Height);
using (Cairo.Context cr = new Cairo.Context(OutputImage)) {
    cr.SetSource (originalImage, RectangleToCropTo.X, RectangleToCropTo.Y);
    cr.Rectangle (RectangleToCropTo);
    cr.Clip ();
    cr.Paint ();
}
```

This additional two parameters supposedly mark from which point the 'source' should be stored (from my understanding, '40, 40' would mean that 'painting' the image would result in the image from 40, 40 and whatever is to the right of and below it).

However, this neither provides me with a cropped image, but instead includes the troublesome offset and starts drawing from the top left of the image.

I also figured that maybe this would be the solution:

```
ImageSurface OutputImage = new ImageSurface (Format.Rgb24, (int)RectangleToCropTo.Width, (int)RectangleToCropTo.Height);
using (Cairo.Context cr = new Cairo.Context(OutputImage)) {
    cr.SetSource (originalImage, RectangleToCropTo.X, RectangleToCropTo.Y);
    cr.Clip ();
    cr.Paint ();
}
```

But to no avail, this simply produces identical results to the previous code chunk.

If any of you could tell me what I'm doing wrong (and it's probably the dumbest of mistakes), I'd appreciate it.

I'm use the Cairo-Sharp that comes with Gtk3.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it. Try this:

```
ImageSurface OutputImage = new ImageSurface (Format.Rgb24, (int)RectangleToCropTo.Width, (int)RectangleToCropTo.Height);
using (Cairo.Context cr = new Cairo.Context(OutputImage)) {
    cr.SetSource (originalImage, -RectangleToCropTo.X, -RectangleToCropTo.Y);
    cr.Paint ();
}
```

The important difference is the negative arguments to SetSource. This places the source image so that the (x, y) pixel from the source falls onto the (0, 0) pixel on the target.

Since you target covers all the pixels needed, your rectangle() and clip() calls aren't needed anymore.

Answer (score 1):

`clip` does not resize the surface, it just masks out anything fur *future* drawing operations.

Create a new surface of proper size and copy the content of the desired (clipped or not) region.